# how to use append in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have created a form in yii and tried using the append method. In said form the user selects the items and enters the amount. If they click the button it will call the function. In output it shows "object text". How do I retrieve it?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction ()
   {
            var newElem = document.createElement ("div");
            newElem.innerHTML =document.createTextNode(amount);
            newElem.style.color = "red";

            var container = document.getElementById ("new");
            container.appendChild (newElem);
        }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'travel1-form',
 'enableClientValidation'=>true,
 'clientOptions'=>array(
  'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
 ),
)); ?>

 <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name',array('name'=>'name'),array('class'=>'addtocarts')); ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
 </div>
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Seattype'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'seattype',
     array('S' => 'Sleeper', 'M' => 'Semi-sleeper','A'=>'Seater'),
              array('empty' => '(Select Type)','name'=>'seattype'));?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'seattype'); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'amount'); ?>
 <?php echo $form->textField($model,'amount',array('name'=>'amount')); ?>
 <?php echo $form->error($model,'amount'); ?>
 </div>
   
</div>
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit',array('name'=>'submit'))?>
     <?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('AddtoCart',array('name'=>'addtocart','onclick'=>'myfunction();'))?>
      <div id="new">
    </div>
     
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the `amount` in your script?

Comment: Try appending it to newElem like this `newElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount))`

Comment: i want to print the amount what the user give..so i just tried with amount in js

Comment: where to give that @anpsmn

Comment: In myfunction() replace this `newElem.innerHTML =document.createTextNode(amount);` with `newElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount))` and also you need to assign `amount` a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your js function like below,

```
<script>
function myfunction ()
         {           
           var container = document.getElementById ("new");
           var newElem = document.createElement ("div");
           newElem.innerHTML =$('#amount').val();
           newElem.style.color = "red";
           container.appendChild (newElem);
        }
</script>
```

this amount `textfield` should include `"id"`,

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'amount'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'amount',array('name'=>'amount','id'=>'amount')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'amount'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `amount` from the textfield and then after creating the text node, append it to the `newElem`.

```js
function myfunction() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;  // amount value from textfield
    var newElem = document.createElement("div");
    
    newElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(amount));
    /* You can also use innerHTML instead of the above line like this newElem.innerHTML = amount; */
    
    newElem.style.color = "red";

    var container = document.getElementById("new");
    container.appendChild(newElem);
}
```

```html
<div id="new"></div>
<input type="text" id="amount" />
<button onclick="myfunction()">Click</button>
```